# how to get xpath by text in python

Tags: python

It's easy for us to get text by `xpath`, but is there any way to get `xpath` by `text` in Python?

eg.

```
 <html><h1>Hello World</h1></html>
```

how to get `xpath` by `Hello World`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the same problem i used this [function](https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf).
Hope this general example will help you.

you have to define the function from the given url:

```
def xpath_soup(element):
    """
    Generate xpath of soup element
    :param element: bs4 text or node
    :return: xpath as string
    """
    components = []
    child = element if element.name else element.parent
    for parent in child.parents:
        """
        @type parent: bs4.element.Tag
        """
        previous = itertools.islice(parent.children, 0,parent.contents.index(child))
        xpath_tag = child.name
        xpath_index = sum(1 for i in previous if i.name == xpath_tag) + 1
        components.append(xpath_tag if xpath_index == 1 else '%s[%d]' % (xpath_tag, xpath_index))
        child = parent
    components.reverse()
    return '/%s' % '/'.join(components)
```

then on python intepreter, run:

```
>>> import re
>>> import itertools
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '<html><body><div><p>Hello World</p></div></body></html>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> elem = soup.find(string=re.compile('Hello World'))
>>> xpath_soup(elem)
'/html/body/div/p'
```

and you have the xpath of the given text

Answer (score 3):

> You can use `contains()`
>
> 1. if you want get the element by using the text inside a tag(Example: h1) use

```
xpath('//h1[contains(text(),"Hello World")]')
```

> 2.If you want to get all the elements that contains text 'Hello World' use

```
xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Hello World")]')
```